# How to add Count if the duplicate index is occur when add list to another list?

Tags: c#, linq

How to add Count if the duplicate index is occur when add list to another list?

Here is Monster class.

```
public class Monster
{
     public int Index { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Count { get; set; }

     public Monster(int index, string name, int count)
      {
            Index = index;
            Name = name;
            Count = count;
      }
}

List<Monster> listA = new List<Monster>();
List<Monster> listB = new List<Monster>();
List<Monster> listC = new List<Monster>();



/* Added some monsters in list A, B, C 
 And union (add range ) all A, B list to list A */
```

And i don't want duplicate index in list A.
But, i only want the duplicate index has just added count.

List A has 600 snails and 300 slimes.
List B has 72 snails.
List C has 300 snails, 371 slimes and 152 trolls.

I want to union all monster lists and show just each monster's count like this.

```
 -All Monsters in world-
 [Index]  [Name]  [Count]
    0      snail    972
    1      slime    671
    10     troll    152
```

Is there have any solutions in Linq for solve this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample and expect result?

Comment: can't make sense of the question sorry...

Comment: @D-Shih I fixed the question!

Comment: To make index unique you can keep index seperate and increment everytime an object is created. dont set the index in constructor simply increment it by 1. If i understood correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use linq `Union` combine those collections then use `GroupBy` and `Sum` get your expect result.

```
List<Monster> listA = new List<Monster>();

listA.Add(new Monster(0, "snails", 600));
listA.Add(new Monster(1, "slimes", 300));

List<Monster> listB = new List<Monster>();
listB.Add(new Monster(0, "snails", 72));

List<Monster> listC = new List<Monster>();
listC.Add(new Monster(0, "snails", 300));
listC.Add(new Monster(1, "slimes", 371));
listC.Add(new Monster(10, "trolls", 152));

var reuslt =  listA
        .Union(listB)
        .Union(listC)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Index ,x.Name })
        .Select(x=> new Monster(x.Key.Index,x.Key.Name,x.Sum(z=>z.Count)));
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1V8Kvn)

**Result**

```
index:0  name:snails  count:972
index:1  name:slimes  count:671
index:10 name:trolls  count:152
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, you are my hero! The key point is group by -> select and Sum()!